# Physical interpretation of conserved quantity along geodesic resulting from geodesic deviation

Tags: general-relativity

A property resulting from the definition of a deviation vector and a tangent vector to a geodesic is that their scalar product is conserved along the geodesic. This can be chosen to be set to 0, so then it is just a statement of orthogonality of the deviation vector with the tangent vector.

Often when one encounters a conserved quantity, however, there is some particular physical interpretation - e.g. Killing vectors also have the property where its scalar product with the tangent vector to any geodesic is conserved along that geodesic, and that is usually some physical quantity associated with symmetries of the metric.

I am thinking that there is no similar interpretation for a deviation vector (since the metric is not directly involved?), and the similarity of the statements of the conserved quantities is somewhat coincidental?